# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ContactController rails & postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model-view-controller

I have an error when i try to create/ edit or destroy a contact from my table.

When i try to create/ edit i have :

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ContactController#create
>
> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function get_xmlbinary() does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64') ^ HINT: No function
>   matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
>   explicit type casts. QUERY: SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64')
>   CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function hc_contact_status() line 3 at IF : INSERT
>   INTO "contact" ("lastname", "firstname", "name", "phone", "email")
>   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"

and when i try to delete:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ContactController#create
>
> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function hstore(contact) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols ^ HINT: No function
>   matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
>   explicit type casts. QUERY: SELECT hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols
>   CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function hc_contact_logger() line 18 at assignment :
>   DELETE FROM "contact" WHERE "contact"."id" = $1

I followed it [guide](http://clarkdave.net/2012/09/postgresql-error-type-hstore-does-not-exist/) to add "hstore" to my application_db but it display `ERROR:  extension "hstore" already exists`

I'm working on an existing database (Salesforce). I get my model controller and views with the command line `rails generate scaffold contact` and i can display content of the database on my browser.

contact_controller.rb:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contacts
  # GET /contacts.json
  def index
    @contact = Contact.all
  end

  # GET /contacts/1
  # GET /contacts/1.json  
  def show
  end

  # GET /contacts/new
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  # GET /contacts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contacts
  # POST /contacts.json
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contacts/1
  # DELETE /contacts/1.json
  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  #contact_url

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :lastname, :firstname, :phone, :email)
    end
end
```

What can it be? do not hesitate to ask if you need some other file

**EDIT**: I found it on PSQL:

> hc_contact_logtrigger AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON
>   salesforce.contact FOR EACH ROW WHEN (get_xmlbinary()::text =
>   'base64'::text) EXECUTE PROCEDURE salesforce.hc_contact_logger()
>
> hc_contact_status_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON
>   salesforce.contact FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
>   salesforce.hc_contact_status()

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "hstore"

  create_table "_hcmeta", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "org_id",  limit: 50
    t.text    "details"
    t.integer "hcver"
  end

  create_table "_sf_event_log", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "table_name",   limit: 128
    t.string   "action",       limit: 7
    t.datetime "synced_at",                default: -> { "now()" }
    t.datetime "sf_timestamp"
    t.string   "sfid",         limit: 20
    t.text     "record"
    t.boolean  "processed"
    t.index ["sfid"], name: "idx__sf_event_log_sfid", using: :btree
    t.index ["table_name", "synced_at"], name: "idx__sf_event_log_comp_key", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "_trigger_last_id", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "trigger_log_id"
  end

  create_table "_trigger_log", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "table_name",   limit: 128
    t.string   "state",        limit: 8
    t.string   "sfid",         limit: 18
    t.datetime "processed_at"
    t.string   "action",       limit: 7
    t.datetime "updated_at",               default: -> { "now()" }
    t.text     "old"
    t.bigint   "txid"
    t.integer  "record_id"
    t.text     "sf_message"
    t.datetime "created_at",               default: -> { "now()" }
    t.text     "values"
    t.integer  "sf_result"
    t.bigint   "processed_tx"
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "_trigger_log_idx_created_at", using: :btree
    t.index ["state", "id"], name: "_trigger_log_idx_state_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["state", "table_name"], name: "_trigger_log_idx_state_table_name", where: "(((state)::text = 'NEW'::text) OR ((state)::text = 'PENDING'::text))", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "_trigger_log_archive", id: :integer, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "table_name",   limit: 128
    t.string   "state",        limit: 8
    t.string   "sfid",         limit: 18
    t.datetime "processed_at"
    t.string   "action",       limit: 7
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "old"
    t.bigint   "txid"
    t.integer  "record_id"
    t.text     "sf_message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.text     "values"
    t.integer  "sf_result"
    t.bigint   "processed_tx"
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "_trigger_log_archive_idx_created_at", using: :btree
    t.index ["record_id"], name: "_trigger_log_archive_idx_record_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["state", "table_name"], name: "_trigger_log_archive_idx_state_table_name", where: "((state)::text = 'FAILED'::text)", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "contact", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "lastname",       limit: 80
    t.string   "firstname",      limit: 40
    t.string   "_hc_lastop",     limit: 32
    t.datetime "systemmodstamp"
    t.string   "name",           limit: 121
    t.text     "_hc_err"
    t.string   "sfid",           limit: 18
    t.string   "phone",          limit: 40
    t.boolean  "isdeleted"
    t.datetime "createddate"
    t.string   "email",          limit: 80
    t.index ["sfid"], name: "hcu_idx_contact_sfid", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["systemmodstamp"], name: "hc_idx_contact_systemmodstamp", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "product2", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "productimage__c"
    t.datetime "createddate"
    t.datetime "systemmodstamp"
    t.boolean  "isdeleted"
    t.string   "sfid",            limit: 18
    t.string   "name",            limit: 255
    t.string   "family",          limit: 40
    t.string   "_hc_lastop",      limit: 32
    t.string   "description",     limit: 4000
    t.string   "productcode",     limit: 255
    t.text     "_hc_err"
    t.index ["sfid"], name: "hcu_idx_product2_sfid", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["systemmodstamp"], name: "hc_idx_product2_systemmodstamp", using: :btree
  end

end
```

Comment: What do you have in your `schema.rb`?

Comment: I solved it, unfortunatly i don't know really how so i can't help. I post mu schema.rb, it could help people who have the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to include "public" schema to your schema_search_path into database.yml

```
default: &default
  ...........
  schema_search_path: "salesforce,public"
```

Connect creates a function called `get_xmlbinary` in the `public` schema of your database, which it uses as part of the sync process. If you remove the `public` schema from your `search_path`, Connect won’t be able to find that function, and sync will fail.